# SQL Server SELECT nested

Tags: sql-server, select, nested

I want to do following two select query result A and B in two `column_A` and `column_B`. I am trying following logic but it doesn't working in SQL Server 2008 R2

```
select Column_A, Column_B

From (

SQL query for A

,

SQL query for B

)
```

Could someone please verify whether my logic is wrong or right?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: do Query A & Query B return a single value or a set of values?

Comment: There are different ways to combine queries. Please specify what you are trying to achieve. You could give examples of what the tables contain and of which result you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest select queries like this

```
SELECT A.Column, B.Column
FROM
    (SELECT Column FROM table1 ...) A
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Column FROM table2 ...) B
    ON A.id = B.id
```

This combines the rows of one data source (table or sub query) with the rows of the other one. If you query from several data sources, you will usually have to join them in some way. If you do not, you will get a Cartesian product, which combines each row of one source with each row of the other source.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want a scalar result do this:

```
SELECT
  (<sub-query for value A>) Column_A,
  (<sub-query for value B>) Column_B
;
```

For scalar result sets you need to **make sure** that they always return only a single value, or the query will fail at run-time.

If you actually want to use sub-queries you need to name them:

```
SELECT Column_A, Column_B
FROM (<sub-query A>) AS A,
     (<sub-query B>) AS B
```

...and you'll want either a `JOIN` condition or `WHERE` clause to properly join the tables together.